# Slicing a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, series, multi-index

I want to slice a `MultiIndex` up to label `NY` for the first level and from label 8 onwards for the second level. How can I do this?

Here is the `MultiIndex`:

[image]

The output should look like this:

```
VA  8  Value
    9  Value 
MD  8  Value
    9  Value
NY  8  Value
    9  Value
```

Below is the code used to generate the `MultiIndex`:

```
states = ['VA','MD','NY','NJ','TX']
cd = list(range(10))
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([states, cd])
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(50), index=idx)
```

Comment: "slice a multiindex up to label 'NY'" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @user17242583, I have related the output, hope it helps.

Comment: @user17242583 the code is mentioned in the bottom

Comment: The states need to be sorted alphabetically first. Does that matter?

Comment: No it doesn't, but that would be a preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort it first with `sort_index`:

```
subset = s.sort_index(level=0)['MD':'NY'].loc[:, 8:9]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
MD  8    0.222916
    9    0.525990
NJ  8    0.888443
    9    0.374329
NY  8    0.569863
    9    0.680583
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This should work as well: ``s.sort_index().loc[slice('MD', 'NY'), slice(8, None)]``

Comment: Oh yeah, cool! But you can condense it even more: `s.sort_index().loc['MD':'NY', 8:]`

Comment: s.sort_index().loc[ :'NY',  8:], this worked for me too.